# SQL Server query split table

Tags: sql-server

Not sure how it calls, I need to do this:

```
+---------------+
| param | value |
|   1   |   3   |
|   1   |   3   |
|   2   |   4   |
|   2   |   4   |
+-------+-------+
```

to

```
+-----------------+
| param1 | param2 |
|    3   |    4   |
|    3   |    4   |
+-------+---------+
```

Is it possible without `INNER JOIN` ?

Where is my error?

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    dbo.RW_ReceivedData.[Value] AS Value1, 
    dbo.RW_ReceivedData.[Value] AS Value2
FROM 
    RW_ReceivedData
WHERE 
    dbo.RW_ReceivedData.LogicalName = CAST(0x01000F0800FF AS varbinary(8000)),  
    dbo.RW_ReceivedData.LogicalName = CAST(0x01000F0800FF AS varbinary(8000))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(4000) 
= STUFF(
    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT ',[' + CAST(param AS VARCHAR(10)) + ']'
        FROM    tbl
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'')

DECLARE @colNames NVARCHAR(4000) 
= STUFF(
    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT ',[' + CAST(param AS VARCHAR(10)) + '] AS param' + CAST(param AS VARCHAR(10))
        FROM    tbl
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'')

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000) = 
'
SELECT  '+@colNames+'
FROM    
(
    SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY param ORDER BY param) n
    FROM    tbl
) t
PIVOT   
(
    MIN(value) FOR param IN ('+@cols+')
) pvt'

EXEC(@sql)
```

Here is **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2967f/1/0)**

This approach uses dynamic `PIVOT`. In order to get the expected result `ROW_NUMBER()` with partitioning was used since values in `param` column are not unique.

**UPDATE**

You can also try it like this, but you have to manually add columns to the query:

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN param = 1 THEN value ELSE 0 END) param1
        , SUM(CASE WHEN param = 2 THEN value ELSE 0 END) param2
        , SUM(CASE WHEN param = 3 THEN value ELSE 0 END) param3
FROM
    (
        SELECT  *
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY param ORDER BY param) num
        FROM    tbl
    ) t
GROUP BY
        num
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9581d/1/0)**

If you don't want columns to be automatically handled, you can just use static `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT  [1] AS param1
        ,[2] AS param2  
FROM    (      
    SELECT  *
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY param ORDER BY param) n      
    FROM    tbl) t  
PIVOT   (      
    MIN(value) FOR param IN ([1],[2])  
) pvt
```

Comment: It there way to do it not so automatically ?:) I would like to use 'SELECT value FROM tbl WHERE param = 1' and 'SELECT value FROM tbl WHERE param = 2' in one query

Comment: @user840250 I updated my answer, maybe this would fit your needs.